# Can the Windows API be utilized using just C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm in the process of teaching myself C (coming from Java).  I appreciate the language a lot, and one of the main reasons I am learning it is so that I can utilize the JNI feature built into Java to write native code when necessary.  My question is mainly about the Windows API.  Can I use the functions and features of the API using just C?

Will the Windows API be compatible with pure C code or does it contain classes and such that can only be utilized by C++ code?

Also, if I compiled a shared library on a Windows machine as (lib.sl NOT lib.dll), would it work on another machine (Mac/Linux)?

Comment: The Win32 API is pure C.

Comment: Very good choice. Let me know when you drop down to assembler level or even to some Verilog :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko We need more people down here Vlad, who else would do the heavy lifting! ;) :P

Comment: Ha.  Thanks for the offer but I'll be sticking to the higher level (I don't mean difficulty.. you probably know that) Computer Science field.  Java is still my favorite language btw!

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 It hurts ! Java won't let you do pointer arithmetic on raw pointers nor will it let you seduce it into thinking it's a raw pointer, now that's not any fun my friend, not a teeny tiny bit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The [Windows API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) (aka Win32 API) is a pure C library.
2. No you cannot use a Windows shared library on another non-Windows machine unless there is a software that supports Windows ABI - such as [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) or [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/).

Comment: ... and very often you cannot even use it on another Windows machine. i.e. on a different architecture.

Comment: @VladLazarenko very often? Do you have a reference of things that are not portable?

Comment: @cli_hlt Bummer!  I hate the lack of portability with C when you only own one platform.  Is there any way to make a shared library for UNIX from a Windows machine?

Comment: Many `MSWindows` programs, especially GUI programs, work just fine on Linux under `wine`.

Comment: What about Mac though?  I realize that Linux is certainly a far better OS, but unfortunately Mac does hold a higher percentage of the market, making it somewhat higher in portability importance.

Comment: 99% of WinAPI functions are stdcall, not cdecl (on x86)

Comment: @Anders with "C calling convention" I didn't mean cdecl ;) I removed the comment for clarity, though.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Seriously? Try using DLL compiled for 64 bit Windows on a 32 bit machine!

Comment: @VladLazarenko oh, I thought you were talking about the API, I misread that we were talking about DLLs. In that case then yes definitely you'd need to recompile.

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 - Um. Mac OSX is certified Unix. Linux is not. And many times the lack of portability has to do with available libraries or hardware differences and not the language.

Comment: @cli_hlt: Well there is no guarantee that stdcall is supported in all C compilers...

Comment: @Anders true, but it is far more likely than, say, g++ understanding cl's c++ name mangling ;)

Answer (score 0):

Win32 API like others have pointed out is pure C. It means, once you get a hold of it, you will know everything about how the Operating system works. It is the same case usually with other operating systems as well. If you are after MFC/COM+ or Java wrappers, it is quite the opposite even if you can build great programs.